# Get all videos from YouTube channel page by page

Tags: python, django, api, youtube

I need get all videos from YouTube channel, page by page. The YouTube API allows one to get 50 videos max.
Now, I get only 25 videos and print in page, using Django pagination. How can I can print all videos from YouTube, on pages?

views.py for video view:

```
YOUTUBE_VIDEO_URL = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=*****&orderby=updated&v=2&alt=jsonc"

class VideoListView(ListView):
    template_name = "video/list.html"
    context_object_name = 'videos'
    paginate_by = 12
    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        request = requests.get(settings.YOUTUBE_VIDEO_URL)
        data_about = simplejson.loads(request.text)
        video_list = []
        for item in data_about['data']['items']:
            video_list.append(item)
        return video_list
```

View:

```
    <div id="list_articles">
                {% if videos %}
                    {% for video in videos %}
                        <div class="article">
                            <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ video.id }}"
                                    width="300" height="225" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            <h2><a class="popup-youtube"
                                   href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={{ video.id }}">{{ video.title }}</a></h2>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% else %}
                    <div class="article">
                        <p>Nothing</p>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
{% if is_paginated %}
        <div id="pages">
            <p> Pages:{% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
                {% ifequal num page_obj.number %}
                    <span class="current"><b>{{ num }}</b></span>
                {% else %}
                    <a href="?page={{ num }}"> {{ num }}</a>
                {% endifequal %}
            {% endfor %}

            </p>
```

I thought to manually get count of videos and div it on page count, but i don't know how realize it

Answer (score 0):

Ok right, so the first part: getting the videos (you will need an api-key, probably multiple for regular use):

This is python but you can convert it to whatever you like, so long as it can send a GET request:

Note: CC defines whether to look for creative-commons videos
You can also look for videos using search

```py
from requests import get
from random import choice

useSearch = True

fname = "output"

if useSearch :
    cc = False
    searchTerm = ""
    apiKeys = []
    apiKey = choice(apiKeys)
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search"
    token = ""
    rDone = 0
    videos = []
    searching = True
    if cc :
        searchTerm = searchTerm + "&videoLicense=creativeCommon&type=video"
    while searching :
        print(url + "?key=" + apiKey + "&q=" + searchTerm + "&part=id&maxResults=50&pageToken=" + token)
        y = get(url + "?key=" + apiKey + "&q=" + searchTerm + "&part=id&maxResults=50&pageToken=" + token).json()
        if y['kind'] == "youtube#searchListResponse" :
            for x in y['items'] :
                if x['id']['kind'] == "youtube#video" :
                    videos.append(x['id']['videoId'])
        rDone = rDone + int(y['pageInfo']['resultsPerPage'])
        if int(y['pageInfo']['totalResults']) <= rDone :
            searching = False
        elif int(y['pageInfo']['resultsPerPage']) > int(y['pageInfo']['totalResults']) :
            searching = False
        else :
            try :
                token = y['nextPageToken']
            except :
                searching = False
else :
    cc = False
    channelID = ""
    apiKeys = ["AIzaSyBTV_7FVKuJBvFEPo1ZkLtXSl7w2Ulg6XY", "AIzaSyAzwkMIvLFYTYz5uHv-Idmq68Er_DzOEkI", "AIzaSyDPGSYUScf6j9A7uE1pWaXxK9j9TCGZbEs"]
    apiKey = choice(apiKeys)
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search"
    token = ""
    rDone = 0
    videos = []
    searching = True
    if cc :
        channelID = channelID + "&videoLicense=creativeCommon&type=video"
    while searching :
        print(url + "?key=" + apiKey + "&channelId=" + channelID + "&part=id&order=date&maxResults=50&pageToken=" + token)
        y = get(url + "?key=" + apiKey + "&channelId=" + channelID + "&part=id&order=date&maxResults=50&pageToken=" + token).json()
        if y['kind'] == "youtube#searchListResponse" :
            for x in y['items'] :
                if x['id']['kind'] == "youtube#video" :
                    videos.append(x['id']['videoId'])
        rDone = rDone + int(y['pageInfo']['resultsPerPage'])
        if int(y['pageInfo']['totalResults']) <= rDone :
            searching = False
        elif int(y['pageInfo']['resultsPerPage']) > int(y['pageInfo']['totalResults']) :
            searching = False
        else :
            try :
                token = y['nextPageToken']
            except :
                searching = False
file = open(fname + ".txt", "w+")
for index in range(len(videos)) :
    video = videos[index]
    if len(videos) - 1 == index :
        file.write(video)
    else :
        file.write(video + "\n")
file.close()
```

Next you will need to divide the output into lists. use something like this:

```py
ls = open("../output.txt", "r").read().split("\n")
def chunks(lst, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]
pages = list(chunks(ls, 10))
```

Pages[0] would be the first page

If you want to use it for a web page, you can turn this into a php friendly thing and use that